# Django queryset with object property that is hitting a database

Tags: python, django

I have a model in Django that has a property which hits a database:

```py
class Post(models.Model):
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

class Comment(models.Model):
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    comment = models.CharField()
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post, related_name='comments')

    @property
    def previous_comment(self):
        try:
            return self.post.comments.filter(created_at__lt=self.created_at).order_by('-created_at')[0]
        except IndexError:
            return None
```

But when I get all comment objects with `Comment.objects.all()`, obviously it is hitting a database each time each object is being included in the queryset to look up previous comment.

I feel like I'm doing this in a very wrong way. How to include previous_comment property in every object inside a queryset without hitting a database multiple times?

Comment: You can build like a doubly linked list with a foreign key to `next` and `prev`

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you want to play around with [prefetch_related](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/querysets/#prefetch-related). I think what you'll need to do is call: 

`Comment.objects.prefetch_related('post__comments').all()`

This should give you a much larger query with a few joins instead of a lot of smaller queries. It took me a while experimenting with these to get them right so I suggest you do the same to get the right balance.